# Can get location of exception with Xcode or explanation... how can I get both?

Tags: cocoa, exception, xcode4.2

If I don't set a breakpoint on exceptions in Xcode 4.2, I get very good explanations, like this one:

```
exception -[NSLayoutManager
_fillGlyphHoleForCharacterRange:startGlyphIndex:desiredNumberOfCharacters:] *** attempted
glyph generation while textStorage is editing.  It is not valid to cause the
layoutManager to do glyph generation while the textStorage is editing
(ie the textStorage has been sent a beginEditing message without a matching endEditing.)
```

If I do set a breakpoint, I get the location of the problem, which is also good. But then I don't get the explanation. Nothing at all is written to the console, even if I continue.

How can I get both? Presumably, since Xcode stopped on the exception, the exception object is somewhere in the debugger when I can get to it.

Answer (score -1):

Enable Zombie Objects for get location of exception:

Go to menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... -> tab Diagnostics -> ON checkbox **Enable Zombie Objects**